# Visualize inertia

Tags: ros, 3d-visualization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

Do you know if there is a way to visualize the inertia of the different links of a urdf? Something like RViz or gazebo displaying the inertia ellipsoid centered on the center of mass...

I could not find anything relevant. Any idea?

Thanks,

Antoine

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192548/visualize-inertia/) by [arennuit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3981/arennuit/) on ROS Answers with karma: 955 on 2014-09-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can actually visualize the inertia under the shape of a box (rather than an ellipsoid - but really who cares) starting from ROS-Indigo / Gazebo 2.2 (you may actually visualize it with an earlier version of Gazebo but there is no ROS version associated).

ROS-Hydro / Gazebo 1.9 does not allow to visualize inertia...

Antoine.

---

Originally posted by [arennuit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3981/arennuit/) with karma: 955 on 2014-09-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0